# Posts not being shown to Facebook Page Fans

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook graph api to post scheduled and draft picture posts to my facebook page. When I post a draft to my page and then schedule it, when the post is published no one sees it. My posts average 700+ views but these all receive 0-1

here is how I am setting a draft with angular js

```
{
    'access_token' : $rootScope.pageToken,
    'caption': $rootScope.postMessage,
    'url': image,
    'published' : false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with:

```
'published' : false
```

This means your post is what's known as a "dark post" - it's present in the Facebook graph but will never be visible on your page, even when the 'scheduled_publish_time' arrives.

Remove this and only use 'scheduled_publish_time', then the post won't show until then (I assume is what you're after?).

Hope that helps :)